# Chrome OS: Security Error

Tags: google-chrome-os

I just installed Google Chrome OS in VirtualBox using this guide: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6770/how-to-run-chrome-os-in-virtualbox/  using this image  http://gdgt.com/google/chrome-os/download/.

It works fine. Except that the first page loading, as well as all pages that require a Google Login, give me this error: The server's security certificate is revoked!

Any idea what this is about?

Answer (score 1):

You should try the new location (that got much better/quality builds) - http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/vanilla.php

I've play with the last build on virtualbox and it's working fine.